# names_pattern in pivot_longer for SD column for ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I looked at all the questionas before with pivot_longer and names_pattern and here is my problem:

```
structure(list(foundation = structure(1:6, .Label = c("authority", 
"care", "fairness", "liberty", "loyalty", "purity"), class = "factor"), 
    mean_MJ = c(7.00782472613459, 8.37558685446009, 8.19327073552426, 
    7.77151799687011, 6.69561815336463, 8.02582159624413), sd_MJ = c(1.36057065528319, 
    1.08658737793234, 1.13782483837514, 1.34475495931994, 1.43635410878014, 
    1.41148324638825), mean_Obj = c(4.9394896079979, 7.49986928104575, 
    6.71334906897456, 5.88003157063931, 4.69680293501048, 6.86677157094152
    ), sd_Obj = c(1.87132702277878, 2.17141631727957, 2.14319145342907, 
    2.17530548192042, 1.80829172434872, 2.57766433904891)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
foundation mean_Obj  mean_MJ   sd_Obj    sd_MJ
1  authority 4.939490 7.007825 1.871327 1.360571
2       care 7.499869 8.375587 2.171416 1.086587
3   fairness 6.713349 8.193271 2.143191 1.137825
4    liberty 5.880032 7.771518 2.175305 1.344755
5    loyalty 4.696803 6.695618 1.808292 1.436354
6     purity 6.866772 8.025822 2.577664 1.411483
```

Here is my data, I want to add fo the graph I created  an error bars. I transformed the data into long format and everything works perfectly apart form the error bars.

Here is my code:

```
df3<- mean_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c("mean_Obj", "mean_MJ"), names_to = c("Measures"), 
               values_to = "val") 
  
  ggplot(df3) + 
    geom_col(aes(x=foundation, y=val, fill = Measures), position ="dodge", width = 0.7)+
    #geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9), width=.2, aes(ymin= Measures-sdObj, ymax=Measures+sdObj))+
    theme_minimal() +
    labs(title="Results: Objectitivity and MJ by Moral Foundations",  
         subtitle="",
         y="Measure", 
         x="Foundation")
```

~I could not figure out how to use either names_pattern or names_sep, so I left with no SD. |Here is the line of code I would have used if I could have had the sd:

```
geom_errorbar(position=position_dodge(.9), width=.2, aes(ymin= Measures-sdObj, ymax=Measures+sdObj))
```

[image: ggplot]E.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the "special `.value` sentinel" (see ?pivot_longer) you could achieve your desired result like so:

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df3 <- mean_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -foundation, names_to = c(".value", "Measures"), names_pattern = "(.*?)_(.*)")

ggplot(df3, aes(x=foundation, y=mean, fill = Measures)) + 
  geom_col(position ="dodge", width = 0.7) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean - sd, ymax = mean + sd), position = position_dodge(.7), width=.2)+
  theme_minimal() +
  labs(title="Results: Objectitivity and MJ by Moral Foundations",  
       subtitle="",
       y="Measure", 
       x="Foundation")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How can I figure out what does this string: "(.*?)_(.*)" mean?
Also, I did not understand why did you use - before the foundation. Could you please explain for future use?
I looked at the .value that you have suggested in the ?pivot_longer but could not understand what did it do

Comment: Easy part. `-foundation` means exclude foundation from pivoting. Shorter than telling which ones to include. Concerning the names pattern. In your case it would be easier to simply use `names_sep = "_"`. Basically `"(.*?)_(.*)"` means exactly that.  For the value columns take all characters before the underscore, for the Measures column all characters after the underscore.